# How do i check if an item is already exist in a List?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
if (this.Handle != hwnd && (Constants.GetWindowLongA(hwnd, Constants.GWL_STYLE) & Constants.TARGETWINDOW) == Constants.TARGETWINDOW)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(100);
    Constants.GetWindowText(hwnd, sb, sb.Capacity);

    Window t = new Window();
    t.Handle = hwnd;
    t.Title = sb.ToString();
    windows.Add(t);
}
```

I want to check that if the item variable (t) is already in the List windows don't add it again. Just after the line `t.Title = sb.ToString();` to check if it's not exist then add it.

Comment: Well you've only just *created* that `Window`, so there won't be a reference to that object in the list. What are you *really* trying to find? Whether there's already a window with the same handle? With the same title?

Comment: To check if with the same Handle not exist. Is there a possible way that more then one window will have the same Handle ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(!windows.Any(window=>window.Handle == t.Handle)){
    windows.Add(t);
}
```

Or, better yet, check at the beginning of the method (although I admit I don't know what it's doing.)

```
if(windows.Any(window=>window.Handle == hwnd)) return;
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you try the `Contains` method?

```
if (!windows.Contains(t)) { windows.Add(t) }
```

That might work.

Comment: This won't work because `Contains` checks for reference equality; he's creating a new object every time so `Contains` will never return `true`.